# Is there exist any policy to save evicted data L1 into L2 GPU cache?

Tags: caching, gpu, gpgpu

I'm doing some research on level 1 and 2 GPU caches. I know about cache design for eviction like inclusive and exclusive but This is a question that came to my mind and I do not know how to look for it.
Is it possible for data evicted from Level 1 cache to go directly to Level 2?

Comment: "dirty" data evicted from L1 cache *always* goes directly to L2.